# Python Cmd: How to edit the last command

Tags: python, python-cmd

I am working on a small command line application based on the Cmd Python module. I can't see how to show the last command in the console prompt so that it can be edited by the user and re-submitted.

**The question is not about how to store the last command. It is about how to shows it in the prompt and allow the user to edit it**

Comment: I think you did not get the question, see the Cmd module

Comment: The `cmd` module does not support something like this. You will have to build your own console interpreter for this, or use something like ncurses.

Comment: why is everyone voting this question down so much, I think it's an OK question?

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs for cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html), `Cmd` has a parameter:

> Cmd.use_rawinput A flag, defaulting to true. If true, cmdloop() uses
>   raw_input() to display a prompt and read the next command; if false,
>   sys.stdout.write() and sys.stdin.readline() are used. (This means that
>   by importing readline, on systems that support it, the interpreter
>   will automatically support Emacs-like line editing and command-history
>   keystrokes.)

I.e., you can use the up arrow to bring up the last command:

```
>>> import cmd
>>> C = cmd.Cmd()
>>> C.cmdloop()
(Cmd) command1
*** Unknown syntax: command1
(Cmd) command1
```

In the final line above, I pressed the up arrow and it remembered my last command.

Answer (score 0):

Just use readline library. You can find example in python doc:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html